# Remote Desktop License servers issue

Tags: windows, rdp

I have a windows 2012 r2 server. I used to RDP to that server without any issues.
Today when I am trying to RDP I am not able to do. It is throwing some errors saying-

> The remote session was disconnected because there are no Remote
>   Desktop License Servers available to provide a license. Please contact
>   the server administrator.

I went through few blogs and tried opening the RDP session using cmdline prompt command-

```
"C:\RDP\MYserver.rdp" /admin
```

In the first attempt I was able to RDP but afterwards NO. Can anyone tell me what is this error and how to fix it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Launch RDP with "MSTSC.EXE /Admin" which will get you a console session logon to the server and bypass any licensing issue.

The error suggests that you have installed the RDS role without properly configuring the licensing side of things. If the RDS role is added it will over ride the inbuilt '2 sessions' that windows server will support with out additional licensing.

Once you get onto the server look at the installed roles and remove the RDS roles that are running.

Alternatively you can configure the licensing role on the same server and then install some licenses, however you would need license keys from MS to do that properly.

Answer (score 0):

This problem made by some kind of caching of remote desktop licensing in clients you can solve this by remove the bellow key in registry:

```
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\MSLicensing
```

It's much convenient to make a reg file and run it so .

1. Make a empty text file
2. Name it "mypatch.reg" or "mypatch.reg"
3. Put bellow text in it and save it

   ```
    Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00

    [-HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\MSLicensing]
   ```
4. Run it by dubble click on file!

It should remove the key.